# Ios 7 Application is crashing

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am developing an application in ios 7. I have used hierarchy of 3 navigation controller.

I got my application crash sometimes while navigating between 3 pages.

-in first page i have just two button. By Clicking on one  it will navigate me to another page in which i am showing data in tableview and also have search bar to search data from that. Then after selecting any one data it is navigating to another page which content details related to that data. So now it work fine but if I navigate more time between these pages then it got crashes. and I am getting crash message near CFRetain count. I have used ARC.

Comment: Add some code. It's hard to say anything without.